# How do I find a <div> tag with a specific attribute value using Xerces-J?

Tags: html-parsing

I am using Xerces in Java. I would like to parse an HTML document to find a div element having a specific attribute (e.g., id = myID). Upon finding said element, I would like to return the text content within the div. I have been unable to find any examples of this online for Xerces.

Example:

```
<div id="myId">foo</div>
```

This should return foo.

Comment: Are you tied to Xerces?  Can you use another library?

Comment: I may not be tied to it, but I am looking for a Java library because I am programming with Java in Hadoop. The main thing I need is speed. I am not really a CS person though, so I am just learning as I go. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry this doesn't answer using Xerces-J, but there is a library called [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) that is made for this sort of thing (though I'm sure Xerces can do this as well).  It's sort of like Javascript for Java.  Jsoup allows you to do something like this:

```
String html = "<div id=\"myId\">foo</div>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
String divfoo = doc.getElementById("myId").text();
System.out.println(divfoo);
```

What do you think?

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I gave it a try using the following:
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(urlString).get();
result = doc.getElementById("myID").text();
The connection timed out on the first step though ... I believe because of a need to go through a proxy on my end. I tried:
System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", myProxy);
System.setProperty("http:proxyPort", myPort);
That didn't seem to help either. On another note though, I did find the documentation for getElementById on Xerces-J.  I am having the same proxy issue with that too though.

Comment: You can try these JVM parameters to get through your proxy: -Dhttp.proxyHost=myproxy.company.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=80  If you are using Eclipse, you can put this in the "VM Arguments" in the "Run Configuration".  If you are doing this on the command line I think you can just enter them right after the java command.

Comment: Yes, I am using Eclipse. I gave it a try but still no go.  I appreciate the help though.